# Add element to existing html using specific location using id and class using prototype insert

Tags: prototypejs, prototype

i am trying to add Element to existing html content using prototype insert. below is the html on which i am working

```
<table id="productGrid_table" class="data" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr class="filter">
        <th>
            <div class="range">
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

here i want to add another < th> in < tr class="filter">, i am trying to achieve this using below prototype code

```
$('filter').insert("<th><div class='field-100'></div></th>");
```

please provide some suggestion what i am doing wrong here???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PrototypeJS *$('filter')* selects element with *id="filter"*. If you want to select by class, then use $$ function. Something like this:

```
$$('.filter')[0].insert("<th><div class='field-100'></div></th>");
```

But I'd recommend either changing class name to something more unique, or use id instead of class.

Comment: In this instance you can make it more unique by using the id from the table as well `$$('#productGrid_table .filter')[0]`